git.overleaf.com authentication fails, doesn't ask for credentials
Since recently I can't pull/push/clone from Overleaf git repos at git.overleaf.com. It used to work well just pasting my access token when prompted. But now I just get the following output without getting a chance to enter my token
$ git pull
remote: Enter your Git authentication token when prompted for a password.
remote: 
remote: You can generate and manage your Git authentication tokens in
remote: your Overleaf Account Settings.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git.overleaf.com/xxxxx/'

I have tried to disable any credential helper with git config --global --unset credential.helper and git credential-cache exit. I deleted my old access tokens and created a new one. Still the same result. It is the same for projects owned by me and those shared with me.
Is this happening to anyone else?
